# Slow X-server performance over network

Tags: networking, xorg, cygwin

I do my development work on a linux virtual machine on a remote computer. I'm using a Windows 7 laptop as my main computer, as it has more screen real-estate, and using Cygwin/X to run my GUI programs from the remote computer.

I've been struggling with the performance of this though, and I've tried a number of different approaches, with varying degrees of success.

1. Standard ssh X-tunneling
2. ssh X-tunneling with compression (`-C`) and faster cyphers (blowfish, arcfour)
3. Direct X client and server (ssh into remote box, run program with `DISPLAY` set to my laptop)

I've gotten all of these to work, but the performance has never been that great. The two computers are communicating over a LAN, connected by 100M ethernet. Watching the windows resource monitor, I find that the X server is never receiving more than about 100 KB/s under large screen refreshes.  I've done file transfers between these computers that go at about 10 MB/s, so I don't think there's a network bottleneck.

Security is not a concern, which is why I'm trying to avoid any encryption that would add overhead.

Why is the network performance so slow, and what can I do to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Might it be feasable to use VNC or a variant on the linux box ?

That might be faster than using the whole cygwin stack.